# unix command to verify span of word in text

Tags: unix, regex, grep, sed, awk

What unix command(s) can I use to determine the line span that a word appears in text? The "span" being equal to the line number of the last instance of a word minus the line number of the first instance of the word.

```
1| unix is on two lines
2| once above, and once below
3| unix
```

In the example above the "span" of 'unix' would be 2 (3-1).

So far I've been trying to make use of grep -n but I don't think that grep is powerful enough. Maybe some use of sed or awk?

Thanks!

Comment: Althoug I already answered. The `span` will be 2 because there are two lines in which the unix word appear or because the unix word apears two times in the same line?

Comment: Span = (last line with 'unix' - first line with 'unix') so because 'unix' appears on lines 1,2,3 (or 0,1,2 if you prefer) 3-1 equals 2 (or again 2-0=2), so the "span" is 2. Sorry that wasn't clear.

Comment: Post edited for clarity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Using `awk`

#### Command

```
awk '{ if($0 ~ /PATTERN/) { if(!FIRST) FIRST=NR; LAST=NR } } END { print LAST-FIRST }' FILE
```

#### How it works

- `awk '{ COMMANDS } END { FINALCOMMAND }' FILE` executes `COMMMANDS` for every line of `FILE`.

  Afterwards, it executes `FINALCOMMAND`.
- `if($0 ~ /PATTERN/) { ... }` checks if `PATTERN` occurs in the line (`$0`).

  If it does, `...` gets executed.
- `The first time the pattern occurs,`FIRST` will be empty.

  Therefore, `if(!FIRST) FIRST=NR` will store the line number (`NR`) in `FIRST`.
- For every occurrence, `LAST=NR` will store the line number (`NR`) in `LAST`.

  After processing all occurrences, `LAST` will hold the line number of the last occurrence.
- `print LAST-FIRST` prints the difference between the last and first line number.

---

### Using only `grep`, `head` and `tail`

#### Script

```
MATCHES=$(grep -n PATTERN FILE)
FIRST=$(echo "$MATCHES" | head -n 1 | grep -Po "^\d+"); [ $FIRST ] || FIRST=0
LAST=$(echo "$MATCHES" | tail -n 1 | grep -Po "^\d+"); [ $LAST ] || LAST=0
SPAN=$(($LAST - $FIRST))
```

#### How it works

- `grep -n PATTERN FILE` shows all lines in `FILE` matching `PATTERN`, preceded by their line number.
- `echo "$MATCHES" | head -n 1` shows the **first** line of `MATCHES`, and `grep -Po "^ *\d+"` filters out everything but the line number.

  Afterwards. `[ $FIRST ] || FIRST=0` checks if `FIRST` has been defined. If it hasn't, it gets set to `0`.
- `echo "$MATCHES" | tail -n 1` shows the **last** line of `MATCHES`, and `grep -Po "^ *\d+"` filters out everything but the line number.

  Afterwards. `[ $LAST ] || LAST=0` checks if `LAST` has been defined. If it hasn't, it gets set to `0`.
- `$(($LAST - $FIRST))` calculates the difference between the last and first line number.

Answer (score 0):

This will find the span between the *first* and *last* occurrence of a word (ie. intermediate words are not considered)...

Note: The `sed` commands `i` and `a` (insert and append) must be the last command on a line.

```
eval "$(sed -ne "1 i b=
                 /\<$word\>/{=; i ;e=
                 =}
                 $ {a ;echo \$((e-b))
                 }
                " "$file" | tr -d '\n')"
```

Or this one, which pipes *sed* to *sed*, but is perhaps simpler.

```
eval "$(sed -n "/\<$word\>/=" "$file" |
        sed -n '1{i b=
             p};${i;e=
             p;   a;echo \$((e-b))
              }' | tr -d '\n')"
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '/unix/=;d' file | sed '1h;$!d;G;s/\n/-/' | bc
```